# être flingué meaning

Tags: expressions, traduction, vocabulaire, usage

Please,  I came across this expression and I couldn't understand it (être flingué) could anyone give me its definition and put it in an example?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you look at a dictionnary first?

Comment: Please change the title of your question to something more specific. Anyone that posts a question hopes someone will answer their question...

Comment: If what you found in a dictionary doesn't seem to fit in the context in which you heard the word, do mention the context in your question.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Did you find anything? OP didn't say they looked in a dictionary but I couldn't find anything satisfying. I don't think it should be on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"être flingué" generally means to be exhausted. Note that this is an extremely familiar expression and can't be used in a professional context (unless you are at ease with your colleagues).

More specifically, "être flingué" can also mean that you are drunk or under the effect of a drug depending on the context.

An example of a use of "être flingué" would be :

> "J'ai super mal dormi, **je suis flingué**"

roughly meaning

> "I slept really poorly, **I'm exhausted**"

Answer (score 2):

In *argot* (the French language used by the underworld), a *flingue* is a gun. Hence, the verb *flinguer* means "to shoot at someone with a gun", or "to kill someone with a gun".
Ex:

> Le terroriste a tenté de fuir, et la police l'a flingué.

Used in familiar usage, it can be used figuratively, and it then means either:

- to break something

  > J'ai tellement joué à la Playstation que j'ai flingué la manette
- to criticize heavily someone or something or to give a bad rating

  > Les professeurs ont tous flingué son travail de fin d'étude.
  >   Le directeur des ventes a flingué les vendeurs qui n'avaient pas atteint leurs objectifs.

*Être flingué* is the passive form of the verb and can be used for any of the meanings above.

Comment: Être flingué c'est être (très) fatigué, je sais pas comment t'as fait pour inclure toutes les autres définitons mais pas celle-là ^^

Comment: *Ce film est flingué par la critique*  - c'est aussi être flingué , non ? Hors contexte (non donné par la question), j'ai donné les sens courants.